# Plot php data into Highmap : HighCharts

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

Hi there I am working with Highmaps JS and what I want to do is to Plot the data from my Database into highMaps . Here's what I have tried.

php Code :

```
$json_data=array(); 

foreach($result as $rec)  
{  
$json_array['Country']=$rec['user_country'];  
$json_array['persons']=$rec['usercountry']; 

$json_array['code']=$keyvalue[$rec['user_country']]; 

array_push($json_data,$json_array);  
}  $data = json_encode($json_data) ;
```

And Here is the script That I Am using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = <?php echo $data ; ?>
Highcharts.mapChart('world-map', {
    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        map: 'custom/world'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'World population 2013 by country'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
     mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Countries',
        color: '#E0E0E0',
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        name: 'Population 2016',
        joinBy: ['iso-a3', 'code3'],
        data: data,
        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.properties.hc-a2}: {point.z} thousands'
        }
    }]
 });
 });
 </script>
```

So What I want is to display the country bubble with the data. but the page don't show anything .its all blank.

The JSON value That I am getting is :

```
[{"Country":"Australia","persons":"5","CountryCode":"AU"}, 
{"Country":"India","persons":"8","CountryCode":"IN"}, 
{"Country":"Mexico","persons":"4","CountryCode":"MX"}, 
{"Country":"Spain","persons":"2","CountryCode":"ES"},
{"Country":"United States","persons":"4","CountryCode":"US"}]
```

The Error I see in console is :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts expects a specific format for each type of series data. For a mapbubble, it needs `{name, z}`. You are trying to give it `{Country, persons}`. Additionally, your join-by is not correct.

Here is a simple javascript code that will transform your JSON data into data that can be ingested by highcharts:

```
data = data.map(function(el){
  return {name: el.Country, z: parseInt(el.persons), 'iso-a2': el.CountryCode}
})
```

This makes the join-by key: 'iso-a2'.

Which makes it all look like this:

```js
var data = [{"Country":"Australia","persons":"5","CountryCode":"AU"}, 
{"Country":"India","persons":"8","CountryCode":"IN"}, 
{"Country":"Mexico","persons":"4","CountryCode":"MX"}, 
{"Country":"Spain","persons":"2","CountryCode":"ES"},
{"Country":"United States","persons":"4","CountryCode":"US"}]
data = data.map(function(el){
 return {name: el.Country, z: parseInt(el.persons), 'iso-a2': el.CountryCode}
})

Highcharts.mapChart('world-map', {
    chart: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        map: 'custom/world'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'World population 2013 by country'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Demo of Highcharts map with bubbles'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
     mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Countries',
        color: '#E0E0E0',
        enableMouseTracking: false
    }, {
        type: 'mapbubble',
        name: 'Population 2016',
       joinBy: 'iso-a2',//'iso-a3', 'code3'],
        data: data,
        minSize: 4,
        maxSize: '12%',
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{point.properties.name}: {point.z} thousands'
        }
    }]
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<div id='world-map'>

</div>
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/yqm78dtp/19/

**API on mapbubble.data:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapbubble.data

Comment: hello sir, your code works. but I have small question that, Can we change the text on  the hovered box from country code to its Country name ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I fixed it now, setting the tooltip to get `point.properties.name` instead of `point.properties.hc-a2`

Comment: That was really Helpful. Thanks for your valuable input.